# Comparing Lists and Printing the Common

Tags: python, list, dictionary, conditional-statements

I have have two Lists that I want to compare and print out the common in both

```
things=['Apple', 'Orange', 'Cherry','banana','dog','door','Chair']
otherThings=['Apple', 'Orange','TV' ,'Cherry','banana','Cat','Pen','Computer','Book']
if (things == otherThings): # this condtion will not work
        print "%s\t%s" % (things, otherThings)
else:
        print "None"
```

**Question:** What is the proper condition should I use in this case?

**Expected Result:**`['Apple', 'Orange','Cherry','banana']`

Comment: you are dealing with `List` not dictionary !!!

Comment: I should fix that (._.)""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert these to [sets instead](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set), then get the intersection of the two.

Code snippet:

```
things = set(['Apple', 'Orange', 'Cherry','banana','dog','door','Chair'])
otherThings = set(['Apple', 'Orange','TV' ,'Cherry','banana','Cat','Pen','Computer','Book'])
print things & otherThings
```

Comment: I get this syntaxError when I use sets!
`things = {'Apple','Orange','Cherry','banana','dog','door','Chair'}
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax'

Comment: Strange.  Which version of Python are you using?  This is running fine with 2.7.8.

Comment: I've revised the snippets so they're backwards compatible.  These have been around since 2.4.

Comment: It returns this error ... I am not sure how to interpret it.
`things = set('Apple', 'Orange', 'Cherry','banana','dog','door','Chair')
TypeError: set expected at most 1 arguments, got 7`

Comment: Oops.  Forgot the list inside.

Answer (score 3):

One way is use `set` and logic `and` :

```
>>> set(things) & set(otherThings)
set(['Orange', 'Cherry', 'Apple', 'banana'])
```

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension will build the list for your "expected result":

```
>>> [thing for thing in things if thing in otherThings]
['Apple', 'Orange', 'Cherry', 'banana']
```

To do the printing thing instead:

```
for thing in things:
    if thing in otherThings:
        print "%s\t%s" % (thing, thing)
```

which will be more like

```
Apple    Apple
...
```